# How to resize a div container background Img to responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I Wanted To Remove Site Title (Text) and Add an Image on that div.

I have Used `visibility: hidden` to hide `h2` element and it's working.
Then I have added an Image to div `.site-branding`

#### The problem is the image's container isn't getting smaller when the viewpoint resizes.

My CSS Code

```
h2.site-title {
visibility: hidden;
    }
.site-branding {
float: none;
background-image: url(https://urltoimagefile/img.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
height: 66px;
 }
```

HTML Structure of Header

```
<div class="bottom-header">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="site-branding">
   <h2 class="site-title"><a href="https://linktosite.com/" 
   rel="home">SITE TITLE</a></h2>
    </div>
    </div>
     </div>
```

I Expect that My Logo Image To be Responsive when viewed point changes. So that Image automatically scales on Mobile Devices

And Also I need to Increase Size of div `.site-branding` Without Increasing size of `.bottom-header`  Because My Image size is Bigger than the div Size

Comment: To change the width of the `.site-branding` DIV in relation to the width of the page you can use the `vw` unit of measurement. You could add `max-width: 100vw;` to the `.site-branding` class.